# Is it correct to say "Master student in Statistics "?

Tags: writing

Currently I'm a student for Master (M.A) degree in Statistics and I need a title for my resume,  does it correct to say "Master student in Statistics "?

thnx!

Comment: I have no idea what 'Master Statistic student' means. Please explain exactly what you mean by this.

Comment: Hi Mari,you right it should be statistics, and i'm now a student for master in statistics.

Comment: You forgot to edit the title!

Comment: thanks tunny (it make me clear I wasn't clear), and thank you Mari, now it's the right form?

Comment: Looking at Google, it seems that *"Master's student in Statistics"* is much more common, although *"Master student"* is occasionally used. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Master+student%2CMaster's+student+in&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMaster%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMaster%20%27s%20student%3B%2Cc0) (you'll have to click search again because there's an apostrophe in the URL). I have no idea what the possessive is doing there; we don't say *"PhD's student"*.

Comment: @PeterShor The possessive seems to be compulsory in both Bachelor's degree and Master's degree, but again not in the case of PhD. The Ngram may be problematic because so many non-native speakers use the phrases incorrectly.

Comment: @painfulenglish: the Ngram may be problematic because "Master student" is used in other contexts. You can fix it by doing an Ngram for "Master('s) student in".

Comment: so it should be "Master's student in Statistics"? and the reason is possessive ?   **many thanks to everyone!!**

Comment: I think master/master's might be a UK/US thing.  In the US saying you were a "master student" would sound like you were a student from some sort of snooty prep school.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to say `Master of Statistics student`, though I think it is not a well-known term. I've heard Master of Arts in Statistics more. Anyway, you can just write `Master's student in statistics` to be on the safe side.

Comment: If OP is studying for a Masters degree then OP is a Master**s** student.

Comment: @A E - completely disagree with you, please provide any valid source of proof. **Bachelor/Master/PhD student** are terms which I have encountered a lot during my life and it will be very difficult for someone to convince me that these are incorrect.

Comment: Might be regional variation. Here in the UK 'Master student' or 'Bachelor student' would be odd usage (although 'PhD student' is normal). Will try to find refs later when I'm not on my mobile phone! ;)

Comment: hmm, strange. I found all three usages acceptable, but google ngrams show `master student` as the most frequently used - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=master+student%2C+master%27s+student%2C+masters+student&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaster%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaster%20%27s%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmasters%20student%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like it could be a BrEng difference then.

Comment: Also, for bachelor, only `bachelor student` is found, so you did not convince me yet.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. Google will provide many examples of "bachelor's student", such as http://www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/CLAS/current-students/BachelorsStudents/Pages/bachelor.aspx . Both forms are in use irrespective of BrE/AmE.

Comment: @Arsen: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Master's+student+in%2C+Master+student+in%2C+Masters+student+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMaster%20%27s%20student%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMasters%20student%20in%3B%2Cc0) should be for *"Master's student"*. It's a possessive. And *"Master student"* is an odd usages in the U.S. as well, although I think *"Bachelor student"* is not.

Comment: Will take `Master's student` as the best option of three from now on.

Comment: Of course, *"bachelor student"* and *"bachelor's student"* are pronounced nearly identically, which could explain why lots of people (who may have only heard the expression orally) are writing *"bachelor student"*.

Answer (score -1):

The correct form would be "Master of Statistics Candidate" or "[degree name] Candidate"

Comment: Your answer would be more authoritative if it cited one or more reference work that support your conclusion. Please consider supplementing your answer with such corroborative evidence.